# Solve the inequality:

Tags: inequality

Solve 
$$x(x-1)(x+3)\leq 0$$

My Attempt:
The corresponding equation of the given inequality is:
$$x(x-1)(x+3)=0$$
So, $x=-3, 0, 1$.

The answer in my book is $x\in (-\infty, -3] \cup [0,1]$.

How do I get these intervals?

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the $x$-axis and to take points $-3$, $0$ and $1$.

Now, for $x>1$ the sign of our expression is $+$ and we have the following signs:
$-$, $+$, $-$ and $+$, which gives the answer
$$(-\infty,-3]\cup[0,1]$$
because degrees of all points are odd and the sign changes.

Comment: Isn't there any numerical method to solve this? I mean without graphs...

Comment: @blue_eyed_... It's the intervals method. By this method it's enough to check the sign in one interval only. I did not draw a graph of out function. I drew the $x$-axis only.

Answer (score 0):

You need either one factor equal to zero, or an odd number of factors negative. As you go from large negative numbers to zero to large positive numbers, every time you pass a zero the sign of one of the factors changes. (note this would be different if you had two factors the same - when one changes sign they both do - so this is something to watch in other similar questions).

So the zeros divide the real line into pieces, and you simply have to check which of the pieces give zero or negative values. The zeros are obvious and for the rest the pieces will alternate in sign.

It is generally helpful to draw a graph if you can't get what's going on without one. It doesn't have to be hugely precise, simply good enough to show what happens between each zero.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use the "snake" (graphical) method, you can try a value from one interval and see if your inequality holds, i.e. for $x<=-3$ we take $x=-4$ and get $-4\cdot(-5)\cdot(-1)=-20\le0$ so for every $x\le3$ the inequality will hold. You also know that on the next interval the inequality will not hold but it will hold on the interval after that one and so forth. This is based on the intermediate value theorem and continuity of the polynomial functions.

Answer (score 0):

After you have solved the three inequalities $x\ge 0;\;x-1\ge 0;\;x+3\ge 0$

you have to consider the product in each interval, like the graph below, and apply the sign rule which let us conclude that the product is $\le 0$ for $x\le -3\lor 0\le x\le 1$ which can be written as intervals

$(-\infty,-3]\cup[0,1]$

Hope this helps

[image]